# Socket IO client does not emit when used outside initial connection

Tags: node.js, vue.js, socket.io

I have a Vue app that sets up a socket connection when the user logs in.
My component has a method that accesses an outer variable socket I made so that I can emit events in other methods..

```
onLoginSuccess() {
     socket = io(`${process.env.SERVER_URL}`);
     socket.emit('login', localStorage.getItem('username'));
     socket.on('login-response', (response) => {
       if (!response.status) {
         alert(response.message);
         return false;
       } else {
         this.$router.push("/home");
         this.$refs.form.reset();
       }
     });
}
```

However, when I try to do socket.emit in another event it doesn't work:

```
    onSocketLogout() {
      console.log('socket logout call', socket)
      socket.emit('delete_username_from_array', localStorage.getItem('username') );
    },
```

Socket doesn't seem to be null/undefined on the console and I tried putting the same event emitter on the onLoginSuccess function and it works fine. It just doesn't work when I use socket in other functions or places outside the initial connection.

Here's my socket io server code:

```
let logged_in_users = [];
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log(`Socket ${socket.id} connected`);

  socket.on('login', function(username){
    // check duplicates
    if(logged_in_users.includes(username)){
      socket.emit('login-response', {
        message: 'It seems that you have already logged in on another browser. Please logout first.',
        status: false
      });
      return false;
    }else{
      socket.emit('login-response', {status: true});
      console.log(`${username} logged in`)
      logged_in_users.push({ username, id: socket.id });
    }
  });

  // for logout
  socket.on('delete_username_from_array', function(username){
    console.log('removing username from array')
    // delete the username from the array of logged in users
    logged_in_users.splice( logged_in_users.indexOf(username), 1 );
  });

  socket.on('test', () => {
    console.log("TEST")
  })

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log(`Socket ${socket.id} disconnected`);
    console.log(logged_in_users)
  })

});
```